# Идентифицировать элементы в двоичных списках с помощью одной цифры

Tags: python, list

```
array = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "f"], ["g"], ["h", "j", "k", "l", "m"]]
```

Есть такой список, представим что у каждого элемента в подписке есть свой уникальный номер начинающийся с 1.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
и тд..
```

Как можно спарсить нужный элемент лишь вводя его номер который я показывал выше, то есть на выходе нужно получить (пример):

```
IN: 1
OUT: a

IN: 5
OUT: f

и тд..
```

Comment: Что не получается?

Comment: Зачем вам вообще исходный список, если вы все равно переменным присваиваете значения? заведите себе словарь или просто возвращайте элементы по индексу списка.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я не знаю как подойти к этой реализации.

Comment: @strawdog переменным не присвоены значения, я лишь привел пример их порядковых номеров.

Comment: @HedgeHog, займите место компьютера. Как бы вы сами решали задачу?

Comment: то есть, речь идет о том, чтобы ваш исходный список списков превратить в плоский список и брать из него индексы букв, вводимых пользователем?

Comment: @strawdog не совсем, нужно с помощью вводимого номера найти элемент в подписках и вернуть его индекс. Извините всегда трудно доношу свою мысль)

Comment: Ну тем не менее, вам нужно попросту получить плоский список и находить в нем буквы по индексам, вводимым пользователем? вроде бы решение очевидно

Comment: @strawdog по сути да, но как понять где эта буква находится в оригинальном списке? к примеру в позиции [1][2] это и нужно понять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ух вам нужно получить координаты значения, то можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

array = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "f"], ["g"], ["h", "j", "k", "l", "m"]]

def get_loc(idx:int):
    letters = []
    [letters.extend(x) for x in array]
    df = pd.DataFrame(array)
    res = df.where(df==letters[idx]).dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1)
    return (letters[idx], res.index[0], res.columns[0])

get_loc(4)
```

> ('f', 1, 2)

То есть, под индексом 4 (начиная с нуля) в плоском списке находится f, которая в исходном списке является вторым элементом первого списка (тоже счет с нуля. если нужно, просто прибавьте в функции единицы).

**UPDATE**

Как выяснилось, элементы в подсписках могут повторятся (неуникальны). В таком случае решение принимает вид:

```
import pandas as pd

array = [["a", "b"], ["c", "a", "f"], ["g"], ["h", "j", "k", "b", "m"]]

def get_loc(idx:int):
    letters = []
    [letters.extend(x) for x in array]
    df = pd.DataFrame(array)
    res = df.where(df==letters[idx]).dropna(how='all').dropna(how="all", axis=1)
    return (letters[idx], tuple(zip(res.index, res.columns)))

get_loc(1)
```

> ('b', ((0, 1), (3, 3)))

Опять же, все считается с нуля.

Comment: Спасибо большое, именно то что нужно :3

Comment: `array = [['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '1'], ['', '1', '', '']]` немного странно работает с таким массивом,  при попытке получить вызовом `get_loc(3)` функция возвращает нулевые индексы что не есть верный ответ.

Comment: Подождите, вы хотите сказать, что у вас в списках могут быть не уникальные элементы?

Comment: да( не все уникальны

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: `да( не все уникальны ` а в вопросе и в примере этого нет.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот, вы как-то криво объясняете, и будем считать, что я так-же криво это понимаю.
Но из ваших приведенных примеров пытаемся извлечь зерна смысла вашего вопроса. И получаем:

```
import itertools
array = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "f"], ["g"], ["h", "j", "k", "l", "m"]]
it=int(input('IN:'))
print('ОUT:',list(itertools.chain(*array ))[it-1])
```

Имеем:

```
IN:1
ОUT: a
```

и

```
IN:5
ОUT: f
```

Если ваш вопрос понят совсем криво, то попытайтесь его переформулировать более "ровно".

Comment: Ваш ответ и есть с точность что я хотел, но вопросик можно ли еще возвращать сам индекс элемента в оригинальном списке? к примеру a находится в [0][0] его и возвращать

Answer (score 2):

Двойной цикл с [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) выдаёт все элементы с индексами. Постройте из них единый справочник, к которому можно обращаться по индексу:

```
def index_items(a):
    for i, b in enumerate(a):
        for j, c in enumerate(b):
            yield i, j, c


a = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "f"], ["g"], ["h", "j", "k", "l", "m"]]
index = tuple(index_items(a))
print(index[4])
```

> ```
> $ python map_enumerate.py
> (1, 2, 'f')
> ```